# What is Weiss Schwarz?

Tags: merchandise

I've been seeing this around the place, but for different series (which have nothing to do with each other like Madoka and Railgun). From what I can gleam off descriptions it's some sort of card game, but the different anime series is confusing me because when I think "Anime Card Game" I think Yu-Gi-Oh, Duel Masters, Bakugan, etc.

[image: Madoka booster]

Comment: Do you want details as to how the game is played?

Comment: @Hopeless_Noob if it's an actual game like Yu-Gi-Oh then yeh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Weiß Schwarz](http://bushiroad.fm/post/en/28/Introduction+to+Wei+Schwarz.html) is a Japanese two-player dueling collectible card game created by [Bushiroad](http://bushiroad.fm/), based around (and in collaboration) with various anime series.

The game is separated into two factions Weiß-side and Schwarz-side, which are German for "white" and "black," respectively.

Here is a better video on how to play the game: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXzMtFp_ZN0